# What is the Grimoire and what is it for?

Tags: destiny

Everyone knows about it, everyone talks about it. But what does it do? What is it for?

With every card collected, you get Grimoire Points.

"I have 1000 Grimoire Points!" 
 
"Uhhhhh... cool?"

Can someone explain what it all means?

Comment: Its all the lore on the Bungie website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a collectible from achieving certain milestones from various activities you do within game. They are viewable only on Bungie's website or within the mobile app. There, you can view all the cards you've unlocked as well as what you need to do to unlock more along with what in-game bonuses they will grant you upon completion. The bonuses the activities grant vary depending on activity and there are three tiers for completion.

While playing the game, you may notice at times achievement like messages informing you how many mob kills or weapon kills you have along with a goal total. These are the activities that once completed will raise your grimoire and grant you some type of in-game perk.

The Strikes Introduction card will allow cloaks, marks, and bonds to drop from any completed strike once you complete the first tier and finish 50 strikes.

Patrols Introduction will grant additional resources for completing city tasks in any destination at tier one which is achieved by completing 50 patrol missions.

When viewing your character on Bungie or within the mobile app, clicking on advisors will show you a list of the bonuses you're closest to acquiring. Hovering or clicking on them will tell you what bonus the task grants. To see what other bonuses there are, you will have to sort through your grimoire. Not all of the cards grant things, but you can also use them to track your stats on how many times you've done a particular thing or kills and the like.

Your grimoire score is tied to your account and the bonuses they grant apply to *all* of your characters.

Comment: *"In-game bonuses they will grant you"* Ahh so there is a purpose to it all.

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding more information on said in-game bonuses.

Comment: And why exactly is the score all about?

Comment: Achievement points would be the best analogy.